# How to move the caption of table generated by kable function in Rmarkdown to the bottom?

Tags: r-markdown, position, kable, caption

The following simple code in `Rmarkdown` will generate a table with a caption on top.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- iris %>% head()
knitr::kable(df, caption = "Table caption is on the top")
```

[image: The output]

Is there any way to move the table caption generated by `kable` function to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the package `{xtable}` which does put table caption at bottom and then pass the xtable object to `kableExtra::xtable2kable` to turn the xtable object into a kable object and then you have the caption at the bottom of the table.

````
```{r message=FALSE}

library(dplyr)
library(xtable)
library(kableExtra)

df <- iris %>% head()

xtable(df, caption = "Table caption is on the top") %>%
  xtable2kable()
```
````

The rendered output looks like

[image: table_caption_at_bottom]

To know more about this caption position issue, follow this [issue-thread](https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/221) on Github.